# Proper encoding for Swedish characters to work

Tags: c#, c++, utf-8, ascii, encode

Here is architecture of my application .

```
Client1(C# code)
SendMsg()
{
String input = "Östen"
  //Send to server Decode API
}


Server (C++ code )
Decode(string messageToSend)
{ 

    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, messageToSend.c_str(),
        messageToSend.length(), nullptr, 0);
    std::wstring utf16_str(size, '\0');
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, messageToSend.c_str(),
        messageToSend.length(), &utf16_str[0], size);

    int utf8_size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16_str.c_str(),
        utf16_str.length(), nullptr, 0,
        nullptr, nullptr);
    std::string utf8_str(utf8_size, '\0');
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16_str.c_str(),
        utf16_str.length(), &utf8_str[0], utf8_size,
        nullptr, nullptr);

}

Client 2 (C# code )
ShowMsg()
{
//Display msg which is received from server
//Here it displays as Ã–sten instead of Östen
}
```

As i told in the the output should be proper Swedish characters .
There are few other clients which uses the same server API call and it is working for them i feel they use the proper encoding .
So i dont want to modify the server code .

Wanted to make changes in Client1 code.
i.e use proper encoding .
I tried UTF-8 , htmlencoding . w1252 . None of them worked for me.

Can any one help me which encoding i must use in the client . So that same same server API will work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to debug either the sender ("client 1"), the server, or the receiver ("client 2") in any way? What is the exact byte-sequence that `client 1" sends? What is the exact byte-sequence that the server receives? What are all those conversions and transformations doing to that byte-sequence? What is the exact byte-sequence that the server sends? And what is the exact byte-sequence that "client 2" receives?

Comment: Also remember that if you're using TCP sockets to send and receive (it's not clear exactly what you mean by "send" and "receive") then you have to remember that you need a protocol to be able to send and receive data in a loop to make sure the whole message is properly transmitted.

Comment: Thanks for the response , my proper is i dont have code for client 2 or i cannot modify the server code .
I can only modify the type of encoding in client 1

Comment: and this these 3 are different windows machines (clients and servers ) , and these are windows applications

Comment: When debugging encoding issues **always look at the underlying bytestream**. What bytes are present in `messageTosend`, `utf16_str`, and `utf8_str`? Have you verified that `showMsg` is happy with a known-good UTF-8 bytestring? (eg `"\x49\x20\xe2\x99\xa5\x20\x75\x6e\xc3\xaf\x63\x6f\x64\x65"` for "I ♥ unïcode")

Comment: Even if you're not allowed to modify the main running server, can you create a temporary debug build? With, for example, debug output? Or perhaps even running it in a debugger yourself? Also, if you're using network communication, have you tried tools like Wireshark to see the actual communication and the raw data that is being transmitted?

Comment: In some cases my hands are tied , so is there a way from just by looking at server side code snippet , can we determine which encoding i can use in my client 1? im sorry if it is dumb qstn

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Östen'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `Ã–sten`. Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…